# Angular: Update data every few seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, intervals

Maybe this question has already been asked, but I searched and tried most of my afternoon without any success so I really hope somebody can help me with this.

I want to be able to update my $http.get() - my data - that I have set in a factory service, every few seconds.

I added some comment to my code and also left some old stuff for you guys to see what I have tried. (the old stuff is also commented out)

My code:

```
    ovwid.factory('recentClients', [
    '$http', 
    '$rootScope',
function ($http, $rootScope) {

    var apiURL = '/plugins/data/get_client.php';
    var promise;

    var recentClients = 
    {
        async: function() 
        {
            if ( !promise ) 
            {   
                // $http returns a promise, which has a 'then' function, which also returns a promise
                promise = 
                $http.get(apiURL)
                    .then(function (response) {
                    // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                    // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
            // Return a promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    }
    return recentClients;
}]);


ovwid.controller(‘client’Ctrl, [
    '$scope',
    'recentClients',
    '$interval',
function ($scope, recentClients, $interval) {

    $scope.loading = true;

    function reloadData() {
        // a call to the async method
        recentClients().async().then(function(data) {
            // console.log(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.client = data;
        });
    }

    // Initizialize function
    reloadData();

    // Start Interval
    var timerData = 
    $interval(function () {
        reloadData();
    }, 1000);  

    // function myIntervalFunction() {
    //     var cancelRefresh = $timeout(function myFunction() {
    //         reloadData();
    //         console.log('data refres')
    //         cancelRefresh = $timeout(myFunction, 5000);
    //     },5000);
    // };

    // myIntervalFunction();

    // $scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
    //         $timeout.cancel(cancelRefresh);
    // });
}]); // [/controller]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues.

First:

`if ( !promise )` is only going to return true the first time. You are assigning it to the `$http` call.

Secondly:

You never access the `async` method in your factory. 
You either need to return that from factory  `return recentClients.async` or call it from scope `recentClients.async().then(..`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am calling the `recentClients.async().then(`. It is called inside the controller.

Comment: I solved it by removing the `!promise` thanks to your observation

Answer (score 1):

may be it will help

```
function reloadData() {
        // a call to the async method
        $scope.loading = true;
        recentClients().then(function(data) {
            // console.log(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.client = data;
        });
    }


// Start Interval
var timerData = 
$interval(function () {
    if(!$scope.loading){
       reloadData();
    }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things :)

`recentClients().then(function(data)...` will not work, in your current code it should be: `recentClients.async().then(function(data)`

(same remark would apply to `` ` `` and `’` qoutes that can get really tricky.

---

This is the syntax I use for designing services:

```
  ovwid.factory('recentClients', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var apiURL = 'aaa.api';

    var recentClients = function() {
      return $http.get(apiURL)
    }

    return {
      recentClients : recentClients
    };
  }]);
```

---

Full example:

*(just create `aaa.api` file with some dummy data, fire up a server and you'll see that data is changing)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sorting stuff</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  var ovwid = angular.module("ovwid", []);

  ovwid.factory('recentClients', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var apiURL = 'aaa.api';

    var recentClients = function() {
      return $http.get(apiURL)
    }

    return {
      recentClients : recentClients
    };
  }]);


ovwid.controller('clientCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'recentClients',
    '$interval',
function ($scope, recentClients, $interval) {

    $scope.loading = true;

    function reloadData() {
        // a call to the async method
        recentClients.recentClients().then(function(response) {
            // console.log(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.client = response.data;
        });
    }

    // Initizialize function
    reloadData();

    // Start Interval
    var timerData = 
    $interval(function () {
        reloadData();
    }, 1000);  

}]);

  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="ovwid" ng-controller="clientCtrl">

  {{ client }}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a service to perform periodic server calls for you.  I had found this code somewhere awhile back and refined it a bit.  I wish I could remember where I got it.

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('timeSrv',['$timeout',function($timeout){

    //-- Variables --//

    var _intervals = {}, _intervalUID = 1;

    //-- Methods --//

    return {
        setInterval : function(op,interval,$scope){
            var _intervalID = _intervalUID++;

            _intervals[_intervalID] = $timeout(function intervalOperation(){
                op($scope || undefined);
                _intervals[_intervalID] = $timeout(intervalOperation,interval);
            },interval);

            return _intervalID;
        }, // end setInterval

        clearInterval : function(id){
            return $timeout.cancel(_intervals[id]);
        } // end clearInterval
    }; // end return
}]); // end timeSrv
```

And then in your controller you'd make a call like so:

```
$scope.getSomethingID = timeSrv.setInterval(function($scope){
    [... Do stuff here - Access another service ...]
},10000,$scope);
```

This will execute the passed function every 10 seconds with the scope of the controller.  You can cancel it at anytime by:

```
timeSrv.clearInterval($scope.getSomethingID);
```

Comment: I guess you could just as easily substitute `$interval` into the service instead.  Think I was dealing with Angular prior to version 1.2 when wrote this service.